# Why do my tests in an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline run twice?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm studying automation in Azure DevOps. My tests are OK, but I can not understand some things. I have two questions ...

1. In my project there is only one test, only one test method. Why does the azure run this test twice? As marked in red on the print.
2. Is there a way to name the tests? Or will they always appear as `TheUntitledTestCaseTest`?

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: I have almost the exact same issue. Reported as a bug on VS community forums here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/672201/test-impact-analysis-detects-tests-twice-runs-test.html

Comment: No answer yet? Im seeing the same thing and its causing false failures. The first run will pass then a test from the second run will fail randomly.

Answer (score 11):

We ran across the same issue on our pipelines and the way we could resolve it was Advanced execution options -> Batch tests-> is selected by default "based on number of tests and agents". When we changed it to "Based on test assemblies" - it works fine. Might help.

[Select Based on test assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzYf5.png)

Comment: I tried this and got the error "The slice of type 'Discovery' is 'Aborted' because of the error : System.Exception: NUnit Adapter 3.15.1.0: Test discovery complete". Anyone else see this?

Comment: This fixed the 'false failures' I was having. It wasn't able to find the assembly on one of the test runs.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue only with some tests. After digging a bit I noticed that I have the tests present in different classes in the agent working folder only, they were not present in the source code.
The cause was that I have renamed some test classes with those tests, but I was not properly cleaned the workspace on getting latest source step.

So setting in my first step "Get sources" Clean to true and clean options to "All build directories" solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with yaml build pipeline to build and test a dotnet solution.

I had 2 separate steps: to run the tests (by `DotNetCoreCLI@2` with command `'test'`), and to publish test results (by `PublishTestResults@2`).

It turned out that the step running the tests automatically publishes the results, so my `PublishTestResults@2` step was duplicating them.

Removing the `PublishTestResults@2` step from the pipeline solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was related to param `testResultsFiles` which was set to default `testResultsFiles: '**/junit*.xml'` so after adding the direct patch to my junit.xml worked fine.

```
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
          testResultsFiles: 'apps/pfp/junit.xml'
          mergeTestResults: false
          failTaskOnFailedTests: true
          testRunTitle: 'Publish Test Results'
        displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
```