# My build pipeline in Azure DevOps running twice for each push

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I tried to build a CI/CD pipeline for my project on Azure DevOps. I was successful for sometime but now i can find that my `dev` branch's code push is initiating the build pipeline for two times, one in `master` pipeline and one in `dev` pipeline and i am also having two releases in my app center. I tries checking triggers and all on my trigers page in Azure DevOps but that wasn't any helpful. Can anyone out there help me out in this. Thank you.

The following is my YAML configuration file:

1. For Master

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
    vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
    inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'key store file'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(keyPassword)'
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'alias'
    apksignerKeyPassword: '$(keyPassword)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.apk'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'artifact'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
    inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'VSAC'
    appSlug: 'app slug'
    appFile: '**/*.apk'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'CICD Release Build'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: 'dist group id'
```

2. For Dev

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
    vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    tasks: 'assembleRelease'

- task: AndroidSigning@3
    inputs:
    apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
    apksignerKeystoreFile: 'key store file'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: '$(keyPassword)'
    apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'alias'
    apksignerKeyPassword: '$(keyPassword)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.apk'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'artifact'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
    inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'VSAC'
    appSlug: 'app slug'
    appFile: '**/*.apk'
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'CICD Release Build'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: 'dist group id'
```

Comment: Please share your yaml configuration or screenshots if you use classic pipelines.

Comment: Hi Madej, i have edited the question you can have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have the [pipeline resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource) defined in master branch yaml configuration? Could you also share the yaml configuration file of your master branch?

Comment: I have edited and added that too Levi.

Comment: @SurajSuddala Is master branch triggered after dev branch is complete? or they are both triggered at the same time?

Comment: I have checked that @LeviLu-MSFT but there is nothing like that.

Comment: @SurajSuddala Do you have some other pipeline that was triggered by the dev push? Could you share a screenshot of the master and dev pipeline runs from the `Recently run pipelines` page?

Comment: I found the answer on this question to be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516776/why-do-my-tests-in-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline-run-twice